# Sqlite3 with android pulling location data saved on database and putting it onto a map

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, location

Hi does anyone know any good tutorials for using sqlite3 with android for saving location data then pullin it and pinning these locations on a map.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a tutorial encapsulating both database AND populating the mapview but i have done what you need and everything you want is explained in the [notepad1 tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) and the [google map tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! i have my map set up with the users location and geocoding carried out on them.. i just want to set up a database and possibly pin the locations of places held in that to the map, or else populate a listview with them